# Dell XPS 13 (2015) Black Screen

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel, dell, xps

## UPDATING:

I followed every step of [this guide](http://hgdev.co/installing-ubuntu-15-04-on-the-xps-13-9343-2015-a-complete-guide/) but still getting the black screen with the system alive and can't go to tty1-6. So now I'm on Ubuntu 15.04 (kernel: 4.1.3-040103-generic). I found this messages from dmesg but i don't think that are related to my main problem:

1. Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
2. psmouse serio1: synaptics: Unable to initialize device.
3. i2c_hid i2c-DLL0665:01: failed to retrieve report from device.

Any help please?

## First Post:

I bought a Dell XPS 13 (2015 - 9343)/QHD+/8GB/256SSD with Windows 8, updated BIOS to A04 and then installed Ubuntu 14.04 (kernel: 3.16). The problem is I'm getting a black screen sometimes after booting, after login and when returning from suspend. I can go to tty1-6 and then CTRL+ALT+F7 that sometimes return to normal but normally it needs a reboot.

I also already tried installing Ubuntu 15.04 (kernel: 3.19) and elementary OS Freya (kernel: 3.16) but always getting the same problem.

```
$ lshw -c video

 *-display               
      description: VGA compatible controller
      product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 2
      bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
      version: 09
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
      configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
      resources: irq:48 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-> efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

I added `xorg-edge` ppa and upgraded but it didn't solve the problem either.
I also installed this packages (http://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukdhs1/SLN297551/en?c=uk&s=gen&cs=&l=en) but still with the problem.

```
$ lshw -c network

  *-network               
      description: Wireless interface
     product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Broadcom Corporation
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
      logical name: wlan0
      version: 03
      serial: ac:d1:b8:c1:0d:6b
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
      configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.1.38 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
      resources: irq:19 memory:f7200000-f7207fff memory:f7000000-f71fffff
```

Comment: What wireless card do you have ? A Broadcom or an Intel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the exact same issue, right now the workaround is to suspend/resume or blindly open terminal through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `xset dpms force off` then just move the mouse and screen should be back.

I still haven't been able to find a real solution.

Comment: have you tried putting that command in the sleep/resume script?

Comment: I have actually put a custom script and associated that to ctrl+super+s to restart the screen.

'xset dpms force off; sleep 1; xset dpms force on'

Comment: thanks man.. the problem  persists but this workaround really did the trick!

Answer (score -1):

take a look here, quite good feedback for XPS13 setup. I'm running A03 + Ubuntu 15.04 Linux 3.19.0-25-generic #26-Ubuntu https://major.io/2015/02/03/linux-support-dell-xps-13-9343-2015-model/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.